# Eclipse. Addition Library To Project

Tags: c++, eclipse, cross-platform

I have instaled Eclipse form repository in Debian it is:

**Version: 3.8.1 Build id: debbuild**

I create project on platform with **MIPS arch**. Ofcorse I have works toolchain, and I tested him, evrything it it ok.
To my project I whant tu add **Library DBus 1.6.8**, this library was also cross compile, so I have got shared library `libdbus-1.so.3.7.2` for MIPS in hide direcytory `dbus-1.6.8/dbus/.lib`s. And n direcytory `/dbus-1.6.8/dbus` can find all header file

```
dbus-1.6.8/dbus$ tree
.
├── dbus-address.c
├── dbus-address.h
├── dbus-arch-deps.h
├── dbus-arch-deps.h.in
├── dbus-auth.c
├── dbus-auth.h
├── dbus-auth-script.c
├── dbus-auth-script.h
├── dbus-auth-util.c
├── dbus-bus.c
├── dbus-bus.h
├── dbus-connection.c
├── dbus-connection.h
├── dbus-connection-internal.h
├── dbus-credentials.c
├── dbus-credentials.h
├── dbus-credentials-util.c
├── dbus-dataslot.c
├── dbus-dataslot.h
├── dbus-errors.c
├── dbus-errors.h
├── dbus-file.c
├── dbus-file.h
├── dbus-file-unix.c
├── dbus-file-win.c
├── dbus.h
├── dbus-hash.c
├── dbus-hash.h
.....
.....
.....
.....
```

Now I whant to add this Cross Compiled library to my project in Eclipse. Yes ofcorse **I have read a few topic in this forum,** I try difrent method but all time I got some error like

> mipsel-linux-gcc -O3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -MMD -MP
>   -MF"src/dbus-1.6.8/tools/dbus-cleanup-sockets.d" -MT"src/dbus-1.6.8/tools/dbus-cleanup-sockets.d" -o "src/dbus-1.6.8/tools/dbus-cleanup-sockets.o"
>   "../src/dbus-1.6.8/tools/dbus-cleanup-sockets.c"
>   ../src/dbus-1.6.8/tools/dbus-cleanup-sockets.c:25:20: fatal error:
>   config.h: No have file or direcytory compilation terminated.

**Now I have add below things**

- I moved whole direcytory dbus-1.6.8 to direcytory with project

In

> Project -> Propoerites -> C/C++ General -> Path & Symbols

- I add to tab **INCLUDE** :
  **/path/form/my/system/MyProject/src/dbus-1.6.8/dbus**
- And to tab **LIBRARIES** :
  **/path/form/my/system/MyProjectsrc/dbus-1.6.8/dbus/libs**

And I gets still above error:

**------------------------------EDIT----------------------------**

I have something changed. I also give error but I feel that I'm more closer solve this problem.

In the:

> Properities -> C/C++ Build  -> Settings

In Tab **Tool Settings** in **Cross G++ Linker** with Libraries I additioned
Window Libraries (-l)

> dbus-l

Window Library search path (-L)

> /my/home/direcytory/Pulpit/dbus_demo/lib/dbus-1.6.8/dbus/.libs

And I get error

> Description   Resource    Path    Location    Type final link failed:
>   Nonrepresentable section on output    Jakis           C/C++ Problem
>   Description   Resource    Path    Location    Type Jakis: hidden symbol `stat' in
>   /home/****/buildroot-eglibc-gcc464/usr/bin/../mipsel-buildroot-linux-gnu/sysroot/usr/lib/libc_nonshared.a(stat.oS)
>   is referenced by DSO  Jakis           C/C++ Problem

and Console output

> mipsel-linux-g++
>   -L/home/.../Pulpit/dbus_demo/lib/dbus-1.6.8/dbus/.libs -o "Jakis"  ./src/communicatorapi.o ./src/dbus.o ./src/filemanager.o ./src/main.o
>   ./src/mediator.o ./src/observer.o ./src/program.o   -ldbus-1
>   /home/.../buildroot-eglibc-gcc464/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/mipsel-buildroot-linux-gnu/4.6.4/../../../../mipsel-buildroot-linux-gnu/bin/ld:
>   warning: libc.so.0, needed by
>   /home/.../Pulpit/dbus_demo/lib/dbus-1.6.8/dbus/.libs/libdbus-1.so,
>   not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
>   /home/.../buildroot-eglibc-gcc464/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/mipsel-buildroot-linux-gnu/4.6.4/../../../../mipsel-buildroot-linux-gnu/bin/ld:
>   Jakis: hidden symbol `stat' in
>   /home/..../buildroot-eglibc-gcc464/usr/bin/../mipsel-buildroot-linux-gnu/sysroot/usr/lib/libc_nonshared.a(stat.oS)
>   is referenced by DSO
>   /home/...../buildroot-eglibc-gcc464/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/mipsel-buildroot-linux-gnu/4.6.4/../../../../mipsel-buildroot-linux-gnu/bin/ld:
>   final link failed: Nonrepresentable section on output makefile:45:
>   polecenia dla obiektu 'Jakis' nie powiodły się